# PNaCl and Google Chrome 40 on Linux: Compile process could not be created

Tags: google-chrome, google-nativeclient

I am trying to run the part1 application in the getting_started directory of the Google Native Client SDK, and I obtain the following message in my browser:

```
 NativeClient: PnaclCoordinator: Compile process could not be created:
```

When I visit the http://localhost:5103 I see the string "Loading...", but it never changes to "Success".

What do I need to configure in Chrome in order to be able to use Native Client applications?

My setup:

- OS: Ubuntu Linux 12.04 LTS
- Browser: Google Chrome 40
- Pepper: 39
- Root access: no

Comment: What does the PNaCl section say in `chrome://components/`? PNaCl is updated similarly to the PDF reader and Flash, so maybe something went wrong on the update side?

Comment: @jfbastien: pnacl - Version: 0.1.0.13992.  No mention of errors, just that no updates are available at this time.

Comment: @JFBastien : did not mean to nacropost. I am on Chromium Version 48.0.2564.10 (dev) Ubuntu 14.04 (64-bit) since I could not install Chrome Dev on my fresh Ubuntu install. I see "pnacl - Version: 0.46.0.4" on chrome://components/.

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer, but a question:

Can you try to get some more log messages out of chrome or the NaCl runtime?

Start chrome from the shell with the environment variable `NACLVERBOSITY=4` set. That asks chrome to show what is going on in the NaCl runtime when it has created a NaCl process (for the compiler). Typical messages are something like:

```
Entered NaClCreateServiceSocket
...
NaClSetUpBootstrapChannel
...
Elf header
...
```

and some more details. If that shows up, we know that NaCl compiler process creation at least made it that far. Could you then post the log somewhere, and I can take a look?

If it doesn't show up, then the problem is earlier in chrome. In this case, running chrome w/ `--enable-logging=stderr -v1` (http://www.chromium.org/for-testers/enable-logging) might give some idea of what is going on in chrome before NaCl process creation.

Answer (score 1):

Same issue.

I changed the `chrome://flags` settings for NaCl for debugging but we are not using the NaCl debugger at all. I set it back to default and it started working. (So I guess that was the problem?)